# How does excel+powerpoint decide to rescale ranges pasted as images?

Tags: excel, copy, powerpoint, scale

I've noticed that when you copy a range in excel (copy as a picture - as shown on screen) and paste it into PowerPoint, the resulting image is not scaled 100% to the original image (right click on image, go to format settings and go to size to see scale info).

In addition, this scaling differs on different computers (might be related to graphics card). If you have different versions of Office the scaling also differs per computer (i.e. in Office 03, scaling is 100% of original, in Office 07, Scaling is ~75% of original for both height and width <---these values may differ on your own computer).

Is there some rhyme and reasoning to how these scalings are determined internally by Office? I ask because I am automating this copy+paste feature through c# (using the interop stuff). I use the CopyAsPicture method to get the height x width of the range selected and save the image as an .emf file. I then load the image into a PowerPoint shape using the dimensions I stored earlier as the dimensions of the shape. It pastes it in without an error, but when I compare it to a native ctrl+c and ctrl+v of excel's paste as picture, the size is different. I've concluded it is because of this weird scaling issue.

As an aside, in c#, if you tell some shape to be 100x100 in size, and insert it (using AddPicture method of shapes), it won't actually be 100x100 in PowerPoint. If you then copy and paste that image into paint to see the dimensions, it'll be something entirely different (for my machine, it upscales it by 135%).

Anyone got any idea what is going on? Or how office decides these scaling issues?

Thanks,
Shark

Comment: Let's eliminate one source of possible confusion right off ... you do understand that the dimensions you use when automating PowerPoint are points, 72 to the inch, not inches or pixels, right?  And to avoid another source of confusion, make sure you're tossing the images onto a blank slide, one with no placeholders.  Otherwise, depending on version, the incoming image may get tossed into a placeholder and scaled to its size.

Comment: I use a 72 somewhere to account for that...Here's the math that goes into what I've done. I use the Clipboard to get the range as an image and store that as a MetaFile (let's say the m.x and m.y for the width and height respectively of the image). Using that, I perform m.x / m.HorizontalResolution * 72 and store that value as my image's width value. I do a similar operation for the width. Let's call these calculated values h and w.

Comment: When drawing the range in PowerPoint, I use the h and w to define the size. If h and w are 100x100, after being drawn, the actual pixel size of this image is 133x134. If I natively performed this operation with ctrl+c and ctrl+v, the range would've had a size of 100x100 pixels. Perhaps my conversation from MetaFile units is wrong and isn't accounting for the upscale correctly.

Comment: After thinking about it, my conversation stores the size (h and w) of the image in units of dots, so when it is used in PowerPoint it is placed in inches. The problem is, this doesn't match the native ctrl+c and ctrl+v, since the native way seems to apply some scaling logic that I haven't figured out.

Comment: You see inches (or cm, depending on your Windows settings) when you look at the size in PPT's formatting dialog boxes, but for programming purposes, everything's in points.  But once again, are you pasting onto a blank slide or one with a placeholder?  Depending on the version of PPT, it makes a difference.

Comment: I've done both types of pasting (native and my code) onto a blank page in PowerPoint. Do you know what logic excel's native copy and paste uses to decide the scale value?

Comment: (bah, can't edit after 5 minutes?) Also, I'll need to have this work on all versions of Office, so if you could explain the differences of each (or link to some resource) that would be greatly appreciated. I've googled my brains out, and can't find anything on this.

Comment: No idea what logic Excel uses for its paste, but is that relevant?  You're pasting into PPT, right?  So for starters, how are you determining the original size in Excel that you're comparing the PPT pasted version to?  And in your code/manually, are you simply pasting or are you using paste special and choosing a specific format?

Comment: The "original size" is determined by the .emf file that is created when I create the metafile and save it. The h and w values I get by the equations I posted above. I carry those h and w values into my paste method. 

Thus if metafile height and width are 125, horizontal and vertical res are 25, the h and w stored are 125/25*72 = 360. I'd use that value to draw the image height and width of the pasted object.

Comment: An EMF can store both vector and raster information; I don't really know what the "meaning" of vertical and horizontal res are for what is primarily a vector greaphic format (albeit one that happens to be capable of including raster images).  Note that you can copy from Excel as picture or as bitmap; are you actually copying as picture?  After pasting to PPT, can you ungroup?  That'd narrow down what we're seeing a bit.    And is the ultimate goal to make the pasted shape some particular size in PPT?  And does it really matter what size PPT pastes?  It's easy to change to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a flaw in my logic: instead of looking at scaling, I should've looked at absolute size. One one of the things I noticed was that regardless of the scaling, the size of the pasted image through the native copy and paste was consistent throughout all the versions of office on all machines. With further analysis, I discovered that the size was determined in two ways:

1) If you selected "copy as image" with the setting for "as shown on screen", I divided the image's height and width (in pixels) by 96 (dpi) to get the size of the image in inches.  I believe this DPI is the default value the Office uses. Then to get it into dots, I needed to multiply this image by 72, since I needed to convert it into the unit that PowerPoint expects on the insert operation. After doing this, the image through my code matched that of the native procedure.

2) If you had selected "as shown when printed" option, my original method worked as we discussed above using the metafiles resolution's to help get the size.

Summary:

**For As Shown On Screen**

```
x = (metafile.height / 96) * 72

y = (metafile.width / 96) * 72
```

**For As Shown When Printed**

```
x = (metafile.height / metafile.HorizontalResolution) * 72

y = (metafile.height / metafile.VerticalResolution) * 72
```