# How to control Excel's scaling of bitmaps

Tags: c#, excel, bitmap

I have a bitmap image and I want to put it in excel. I used this code I found [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-insert-picture-excel.htm):

```
xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\\filesystem\\mb2.bmp", 
    msoFalse, msoCTrue, 0, 0, 518, 390);
```

But the resulting image is `1.333` times wider and higher. OK, so I can just multiply the dimensions by `0.75` and I get an image in excel with the desired dimensions.

```
xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\\filesystem\\mb2.bmp", 
    msoFalse, msoCTrue, 0, 0, (float)(518*0.75), (float)(390*0.75));
```

But that number `0.75` sitting there hard-coded really bothers me. Especially since I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367575/interop-shapes-addpicture-creates-incorrect-dimension-for-image) in which the op's ratio is `0.76`. Knowing that this code needs to run on any number of systems with different displays, I want to know how to get the ratio programmatically.

Somewhat also related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274714/how-does-excelpowerpoint-decide-to-rescale-ranges-pasted-as-images) which has to do with copy-paste without code.

Comment: Do you want that relative to the window or relative to their monitor?

Comment: It's going into a file that will be printed as a datasheet. The way the page is set up that image size is what we need in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about printing, the display is irrelevant.

The dimensions of the image need to be relative to the paper size.  The size values in the `AddPicture` method are in points and are only loosely related to pixels.  Points are units if measure that make sense to your printer.  The application translates points to pixels for you so you don't need to worry about that.

You can use the `InchesToPoints` or `CentimetersToPoints` methods of the `Application` object to size your image to paper size.

Comment: Looks promising I will try first thing tomorrow